# PhantomJS cutting/splitting words in half across page breaks

Tags: css, node.js, phantomjs, pdf-generation, page-break

I am using the phantomjs-node api to render a PDF. The problem is that words that appear near the end of a page are split across 2 pages, half the word on page 1, other half on page 2. I cannot understand why this is happening. What can I do to fix this? I already [created an issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14892) on phantomjs github with no response yet.

The length of data is unknown until runtime so I don't see it being feasible to put a hard page break in the rows of data.

1. Which version of PhantomJS are you using? 
   [phantomjs-node ^v2.1.21](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node)
2. What steps will reproduce the problem?

   a. Create multi page website

   b. Render as pdf
3. Which operating system are you using?
   windows 10 x64
4. Did you use binary PhantomJS or did you compile it from source?
   [phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) pre-compiled
5. Please provide any additional information below.

[image: phantomjs_cutting_words_in_half_across_page_breaks]

Comment: Anything findout? Please share with us.

Comment: @higunjan Yes, phantomjs is now fully deprecated and unsupported. You should switch to modern PDF generation techniques such as using Chrome Headless. A library called `puppeteer` makes this very easy, I switched over with no problems. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Thank you. I will check and get back to you soon.

Comment: Thanks It's working properly.

Comment: Hello, I found issues with `puppeteer`. It won't run on a server. `( CentOS 6.9 )` . `(node:10767) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!`

Comment: @higunjan This means that the server does not have the dependencies needed to launch Chrome. Pupeteer comes with its own version chromium bundled with it, but your server needs all the libraries for it to run. See: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/391#issuecomment-325420271

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018-05-03 (Mar. 3) the **development of PhantomJS is suspended** due to lack of active contribution and it is archived. [**Link**](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344)

Because of this update, I recommend Google's official headless wrapper around Chrome, [**puppeteer**](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

---

Install:

`npm i puppeteer`

Usage:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

---

## Note

**This answer won't provide a helpful answer to your question, but sadly, you'll face the fact, that you have to leave PhantomJS and switch to another headless solution, sooner or later...** Our team have faced with this issue, we chose [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

Comment: Yes I have already long since left phantomjs and switched indeed to Puppeteer which works great, and webfonts work to boot.